# Where can i get Google Location based api or url from where i get xml with data?

Tags: ios4, google-maps-api-3, xml-parsing

I want to make some searching related operation like pub searching from my native application using google api  and also get the complete address of that pub with latitude and Longitude so anybody have idea regarding this? From where i should get data in xml format so i can parse and display it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use google-maps-api for this. Instead, use Google Places API to load the pub/restaurant locations. [Google Places API link.](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/)